# Code for the analysis of Scores

Tags: python, python-3.x

We represent scores of batsmen across a sequence of matches in a two level dictionary as follows:

```
{'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}
```

Each match is identified by a string, as is each player.  The scores are all integers.  The names associated with the matches are not fixed (here they are 'match1','match2','match3'), nor are the names of the players.  A player need not have a score recorded in all matches

Define a Python function "orangecap(d)" that reads a dictionary d of this form and identifies the player with the highest total score.  Your function should return a pair (playername,topscore) where playername is a string, the name of the player with the highest score, and topscore is an integer, the total score of playername.

The input will be such that there are never any ties for highest total score.

For instance:

```
>>> orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}})
('player3', 100)

>>> orangecap({'test1':{'Ashwin':84, 'Kohli':120}, 'test2':{'ashwin':59, 'Pujara':42}})
('Kohli', 120)
```

Comment: and *what* exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code wringing service. If you want somebody to do your homework for you, you are (hopefully) out of luck. Instead, you should try solving the problem on your own. If you run into problems, then come and describe them to us and we'll be happy to help you figure out what is wrong and how to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'get' method to return a default of zero then add. Like this:

```
adict = {'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38},
        'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42},
        'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}

def orangecap(dict1):
    dict2 = {}
    for k1 in dict1:
        for k2 in dict1[k1]:
            dict2[k2] = dict2.get(k2, 0) + dict1[k1][k2]
    player = max(dict2, key=dict2.get)
    return player, dict2[player]

print (orangecap(adict))


>>> adict = {'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38},
        'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42},
        'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}}


>>> print (orangecap(adict))
('player3', 100)
>>>
```